# Fragment already added issue, when using navigation with bottom navigation bar android

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, uinavigationcontroller, androidx, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view which I have implemented in androidx navigation, but the problem is it is showing me the error of

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: BaseFragment{27d5b00 (2156a830-7756-4fc9-bc63-7c6f3d6705f0) id=0x7f08008c android:switcher:2131230860:0}
```

I have a base fragment which provides views to different fragments

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener,
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    // overall back stack of containers
    private val backStack = Stack<Int>()

    // list of base destination containers
    private val fragments = listOf(
            BaseFragment.newInstance(R.layout.content_home_base, R.id.toolbar_home, R.id.nav_host_home),
            BaseFragment.newInstance(R.layout.content_library_base, R.id.toolbar_library, R.id.nav_host_library),
            BaseFragment.newInstance(R.layout.content_settings_base, R.id.toolbar_settings, R.id.nav_host_settings))


    // map of navigation_id to container index
    private val indexToPage = mapOf(0 to R.id.home, 1 to R.id.library, 2 to R.id.settings)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // setup main view pager
        main_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
        main_pager.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter()
        main_pager.post(this::checkDeepLink)
        main_pager.offscreenPageLimit = fragments.size

        // set bottom nav
        bottom_nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        bottom_nav.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(this)


        // initialize backStack with elements
        if (backStack.empty()) backStack.push(0)
    }

    /// BottomNavigationView ItemSelected Implementation
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val position = indexToPage.values.indexOf(item.itemId)
        if (main_pager.currentItem != position) setItem(position)
        return true
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemReselected(item: MenuItem) {
        val position = indexToPage.values.indexOf(item.itemId)
        val fragment = fragments[position]
        fragment.popToRoot()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val fragment = fragments[main_pager.currentItem]
        val hadNestedFragments = fragment.onBackPressed()
        // if no fragments were popped
        if (!hadNestedFragments) {
            if (backStack.size > 1) {
                // remove current position from stack
                backStack.pop()
                // set the next item in stack as current
                main_pager.currentItem = backStack.peek()

            } else super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    /// OnPageSelected Listener Implementation
    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}

    override fun onPageScrolled(p0: Int, p1: Float, p2: Int) {}

    override fun onPageSelected(page: Int) {
        val itemId = indexToPage[page] ?: R.id.home
        if (bottom_nav.selectedItemId != itemId) bottom_nav.selectedItemId = itemId
    }

    private fun setItem(position: Int) {
        main_pager.currentItem = position
        backStack.push(position)
    }

    private fun checkDeepLink() {
        fragments.forEachIndexed { index, fragment ->
            val hasDeepLink = fragment.handleDeepLink(intent)
            if (hasDeepLink) setItem(index)
        }
    }

    inner class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = fragments[position]

        override fun getCount(): Int = fragments.size

    }
}
```

Base Fragment Class :

```
class BaseFragment: Fragment() {

    private val defaultInt = -1
    private var layoutRes: Int = -1
    private var toolbarId: Int = -1
    private var navHostId: Int = -1
    private val appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(rootDestinations)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            layoutRes = it.getInt(KEY_LAYOUT)
            toolbarId = it.getInt(KEY_TOOLBAR)
            navHostId = it.getInt(KEY_NAV_HOST)

        } ?: return
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return if (layoutRes == defaultInt) null
        else inflater.inflate(layoutRes, container, false)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // return early if no arguments were parsed
        if (toolbarId == defaultInt || navHostId == defaultInt) return

        // setup navigation with toolbar
        val toolbar = requireActivity().findViewById<Toolbar>(toolbarId)
        val navController = requireActivity().findNavController(navHostId)

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfig)

//        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar,navController)
    }

    fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
        return requireActivity()
                .findNavController(navHostId)
                .navigateUp(appBarConfig)
    }


    fun popToRoot() {
        val navController = requireActivity().findNavController(navHostId)
        navController.popBackStack(navController.graph.startDestination, false)
    }

    fun handleDeepLink(intent: Intent) = requireActivity().findNavController(navHostId).handleDeepLink(intent)


    companion object {

        private const val KEY_LAYOUT = "layout_key"
        private const val KEY_TOOLBAR = "toolbar_key"
        private const val KEY_NAV_HOST = "nav_host_key"

        fun newInstance(layoutRes: Int, toolbarId: Int, navHostId: Int) = BaseFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt(KEY_LAYOUT, layoutRes)
                putInt(KEY_TOOLBAR, toolbarId)
                putInt(KEY_NAV_HOST, navHostId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried empty the stack first but that did not work, i have three navgraphs for my three viewpager elements/ fragments.

Answer (score 2):

We reverted back back to 2.1.0 (nav library) and it worked again

Answer (score 1):

Error is not quite connected with Navigation library. It's most probably fragment's error itself. Try testing that fragment in empty activity without using Navigation.

Navigation library is somehow treating error wrongly.

p.s. in my case it was just and view's id missing in layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support, I found the solution I created different navigation graphs for each page.